# How to read/understand the code behind TF/Keras API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I started using Tensorflow/Keras for basics Neural Networks architectures such as Feed-Forward networks or RNN.

Although it is working well and there are plenty of information on how this works, in principle, on the internet, I could not find any direct explanation of Tensorflow/Keras source code.

When I have a look in the source directory of the package, there are thousands of files and there is virtually no way (at least for me) to find relevant information in this. It seems everything is highly nested and I can't find the code corresponding to the maths behind layers I call.

So I'd like someone to provide tips on how to find such information in Tensorflow/Keras code or any resource that comments the inner working of basic networks directly linked with the source of the API implementation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am unsure Tensorflow/Keras has ever been made to be "used" for this purpose.

You may want to look at [EpyNN](https://github.com/synthaze/epynn).

This is an educational project which provides API, examples and documentation website. The source code is written to be read.

While this is basic compared to Tensorflow/Keras, what it provides has been validated against it. For identical configurations results are identical. So you could use that to understand, somehow, the *necessary* part of what's behind Tensorflow/Keras API for the basic use you mention.

Disclaimer: I am the main author of EpyNN.

Comment: This seems to fit exactly to what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Synthase @mvallet FYI, `tf. keras` does provide lots of resources for such purposes. Please pay visit to [keras.io](https://keras.io/api/). Also, check these [resources](https://keras.io/getting_started/), introduction notebook for researchers and engineers.

Comment: @M.Innat actually not. What tf. keras does not provide is a concise and readable source code. There is 1290 python files for 330 000 lines of code in tensorflow/python. The OP is asking, basically, for an API he could understand by reading the source code behind.